# Logistic regression in R gives 100% accuracy, but if i export the result file it gives different results

Tags: r

I am using R for logistic regression and I am getting 100% accuracy in confusion matrix but when i export data the actual prediction values show a different result. Can some one please help.

###Code

```
    set.seed(123)
    gi.train_ind <- 
    sample(1:nrow(gifraud),size=floor(0.80*nrow(gifraud)))
    gi.train <- gifraud[gi.train_ind,]
    gi.test <- gifraud[-gi.train_ind,]


    logreg <- glm(fraud_reported~CurrentReferralStatus

    +IsReportedToPolice+HasPreviousClaims+ 
    EstimatedInitialClaimCost+HasComplaint+IsPolicyholderVerified, 
    data=gi.train, family =binomial)


    summary (logreg)

    gi.train$probscore <- predict(logreg,data=gi.train, type ="response")
    gi.train$prediction <- as.factor (ifelse(gi.train$probscore <0.5, 0,1))



    gi.test$probscore <- predict(logreg,gi.test, type ="response")
    gi.test$prediction <- as.factor (ifelse(gi.test$probscore <0.5, 0,1))



    install.packages('caret')
    install.packages('e1071', dependencies=TRUE)
    library(caret)

    confusionMatrix(gi.train$fraud_reported, gi.train$fraud_reported)
    confusionMatrix(gi.test$fraud_reported, gi.test$fraud_reported)

    prop.table(table(gi.test$fraud_reported,gi.test$probscore>0.5))
    prop.table(table(gi.train$fraud_reported,gi.test$probscore>0.5))


    write.csv(gi.train, file ="GItrainresults.csv")
    write.csv(gi.test, file ="GItestresults.csv")
```

The exported files shows correct results at around 87% but the confusion matrix is showing 100%

Comment: in your `confusionMatrix()` function you compare the true values to themselves. You have to do  `confusionMatrix(gi.test$fraud_reported, gi.test$prediction)`

Comment: Thank you mate, that was a stupid oversight guess multiple sleepless night have caused this.

Answer (score 1):

Confusion matrix is used to interpret model results between predicted and actual target variable.
You are basically doing confusion matrix between actual target variables

Comment: Thank you !  is this warning message something i should be worried about, apologies i am new to R ----Warning message:
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

Comment: Check this article: https://discuss.analyticsvidhya.com/t/glm-fit-fitted-probabilities-numerically-0-or-1-occurred-warning-message-when-i-run-logistic-regression/10390/6